# New SVG logo - menu does not work Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, svg, vector

Since I changed logo to SVG, menu does not work. Maybe transparency of logo covers menu?

When I do: display: none for logo, menu works well.

Could please somebody help me?

Website: http://www.1.moneymagnet.store/

Comment: First of all: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it Please act accordingly on your future questions.

Comment: And yes, you logos cover the whole width of the menu, because your `.logo-holder` element that you put them in has `width: 100%` set.

Comment: But when I remove width: 100% my logo disappears. Do you know how I can solve it?

Comment: You need to give it a width, just not 100% …

Answer (score 0):

Your logo holder is all over the whole thing (`width: 100%;`). It's getting this style from an inline style-sheet. That's why your menu is not working.

Just give it a fixed width and everything will work as expected:

```
.logo-holder {
   width: 110px;
}
```

Look out for specificity on your selector though.